# Use custom version of assembly for all dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, assemblies

My project uses a [modified version](https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity) of the Newtonsoft.Json library with some changes so that it will play nice with AOT. The modified dll has been added as reference assembly of the project. My project also uses a set of additional libraries (some via Nuget, some via additional project includes), and some of these libraries also have their own dependency on Newtonsoft.Json.

1. Which version of Newtonsoft.Json will be included in the final build?
2. Can I map all versions to use the modified library? Maybe via a BindingRedirect?

Comment: Can you share the example of  project file?

Comment: Can your modified version be built to have a different name?

Comment: @JoeSewell Sure, I can adjust the name or version if needed. I just need that all the libraries within the project also use the modified version, else they will not function.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I could make a snippet with private information removed. Is there something in particular you are looking for in the project that would help?

Comment: @AndySavage It may even work without `BindingRedirect`. The final build will include the version which is referenced by your project at the time of the build. If you remove the Newtonsoft.Json added to your project by your nuget references and just add that modified dll directly it may work fine without any configuration, but it depends on what versions required by your referenced dlls. The problem is that when you update your nuget packages next time they'll overwrite this custom reference with their own Newtonsoft.Json version and I'm not sure how to tell them not to do this.

Comment: Your forked library has another NuGet package name. So technically, it's another library and it cannot be used instead of standard one in third-party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to make external libraries load your dll using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve

1. Make your fork dll have a different name than Newtonsoft.Json
2. Reference it in your project
3. In the post build event add a command line to delete Newtonsoft.Json.dll from the target dir
4. as the first code line of your project (inside Program.cs in case of windows applications and inside Global.asax Application_Start in case of web applications) add this code:

> ```
> AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += 
>     (s, a) => {
>         if (a.Name.Contains("Newtonsoft.Json"))
>           return Assembly.LoadFrom(@"PATH TO YOUR DLL HERE");
>         else
>           return null;
>               };
> ```

In case of web application you can get the path to your dll using Server.MapPath